# How to move 3 alphabets backwards in lowercase letter?

Tags: java, kotlin, encryption, cryptography, caesar-cipher

I am trying to implement Caesar Cipher in Kotlin. In Caesar Cipher you encrypt the message by substituting a letter with some fixed number of positions down the alphabet. You can look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/caesar-cipher-in-cryptography/) for more information and also the approach I adopted for encryption and decryption.

My encryption works properly.

*Note: s is for a shift in alphabets and I have kept it as 3 by default.*

```
fun encrypt(message:String,s:Int=3):String{
    var encrpt:String = ""
    for(m in message){
        if(m.isLetter() && m.isUpperCase())
            encrpt+=((m + s - 65).toInt() % 26 + 65).toChar()

        else if(m.isLetter() && m.isLowerCase())
            encrpt+=((m + s - 97).toInt() % 26 + 97).toChar()

        else
            encrpt+=m
    }
    return encrpt
}
```

For decryption instead of adding 3, I am subtracting 3. But I am facing some problem in decryption and that too only for lower case letters.

This is my code for decryption:

```
fun decrypt(message:String,s:Int=3):String{
    var decrpt:String = ""
    for(m in message){
        if(m.isLetter() && m.isUpperCase())
            decrpt+=((m - s + 65).toInt() % 26 + 65).toChar()

        else if(m.isLetter() && m.isLowerCase())
            decrpt+=((m - s + 97).toInt() % 26 + 97).toChar()

        else
            decrpt+=m
    }
    return decrpt
}
```

For uppercase letters my output is fine:

J->G

But for lowercase letters, the output is incorrect.

j->s

I have used [this](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-b6203f45919e28842032627b2fdf46aa) image for the decimal values of characters. Thank you for looking into my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I just noticed some instructions given by the author for decryption [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/caesar-cipher-in-cryptography/) at the end.

> we can use the same function to decrypt, instead we’ll modify the shift value such that shift = 26-shift

So now decryption function looks like this:

```
fun decrypt(message:String,s:Int=3):String{
var decrpt:String = ""
for(m in message){
    if(m.isLetter() && m.isUpperCase())
        decrpt+=((m + (26-s) - 65).toInt() % 26 + 65).toChar()

    else if(m.isLetter() && m.isLowerCase())
        decrpt+=((m + (26-s) - 97).toInt() % 26 + 97).toChar()

    else
        decrpt+=m
}
return decrpt
}
```

Still, I am curious to know if I can use the same shift in the opposite direction to decrypt the encrypted text.

Answer (score 0):

The handling of both the upper-case and lower-case decryption here is wrong. Subtracting `s` is correct, but you need to also **subtract** 65 or 97 ('a' or 'A'), in order to be able to perform a modulu operation:

```
fun decrypt(message:String,s:Int=3):String{
    var decrpt:String = ""
    for(m in message){
        if(m.isLetter() && m.isUpperCase())
            decrpt+=((m - s - 65).toInt() % 26 + 65).toChar()

        else if(m.isLetter() && m.isLowerCase())
            decrpt+=((m - s - 97).toInt() % 26 + 97).toChar()

        else
            decrpt+=m
    }
    return decrpt
}
```

Comment: But now if I pass zZ as a String to my encrypt function it gives cC as an output which is correct but on passing this cC to my decrypt function the output is pP instead of zZ.